# Jumps of Refresh Time on Elasticsearch Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fight occasional spikes in Refresh Time on my logging service for API calls. 
Almost all of the requests to server are index/update pairs with refresh_interval -1.
_refresh is called from cronjob every minute, but the spikes happen only 1-4 times per hour. The spikes are usually 6-8s.

[image: Refresh Time]

Translog durability is set to async.
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 50%

Or maybe it's just completely normal? I have no comparison, all my other projects do not index that many records.
On average there are 170k index operations daily.
I am not using bulk indexing, it's not possible in this scenario.

Thank you for all suggestions!
Marcin

Comment: Do you index in bulk and do you refresh the index while indexing ?

Comment: Dear Christophe,
To put it short: I refresh while indexing.
Thank you,
Marcin

Comment: For performance the best is usually to bulk import while indexing is off.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

Comment: why you couldn't do bulk indexing?

Comment: I use ES for logging request/response to an external API. Each HTTP request consists of: 1. index call before external API call, 2. update call with response received. It all has to work within a single http request. It is not a perfect case for ES.

Comment: What would you use for a local queue of documents for indexing?

Answer (score 0):

For performance the best is usually to [bulk import](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) while indexing is off but it depends:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html#_choosing_which_setting_to_use

Many tips here:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Comment: Thank you but I implemented all the tips already with the exception of Bulk Indexing. I wonder why refresh sometimes takes 1s and sometimes 8s?

Comment: Have you seen and implemented the other tips ?

Comment: Dear Christophe,
Yes - before I created this thread. I also researched many articles on speeding up the indexing. The only thing I could not implement is bulk indexing.
Thank you,
Marcin

Comment: In that case you may have some hardware/performance issues. Also tune your JVM ... perhaps it is garbage collection related.

Comment: Do you have any tips for me regarding JVM garbage collection issues? I included little bit more info on elastic forums, maybe you could have  a look at monitoring if you see anything odd in particular:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timeouts-when-indexing/124591
Thank you so much!

Comment: Dear Christophe,
No problem - I am grateful for you help anyway.
Happy Easter!
Marcin

Comment: I think I will try to implement a queue in Redis and a consumer for bulk indexing as cronjob.